# Lumen: Foreign key constraint violation when inserting data one to many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I am in the process of learning how inserting with the relationships many to many and one to many. Currently I got stucked in a foreign key constraint when I try to create a new item.

My code is really simple:

```
$this->model->create(
    $request->all()
);
```

Where the request has the item id and the item exists.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

What can be a solution for this?

Comment: We are going to need a little more data, What does your migration look like for the tables and what is sent with the request, and what does your model look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a foreign key. For example, if you have User has many Articles relationship and you're trying to insert a new Article, you need to do this:

```
$user->articles()->create($request->all()); // Foreign key will be inserted automatically.
```

Or specify foreign key:

```
$this->article->create(array_merge(['user_id' => auth()->id()], $request->all()));
```

Comment: Looks like the first example helped me, thank you very much. But the second one didnt. So if I have the user object and use the relation and pass the request everything is fine. If in the construct I set my article model and pass the user_id via array_merge or in the $request->all, i will still get the foreign key constraint, which is strange ...